# Display Pagination for smartphone & desktop

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, themes, genesis

I want to show **number pagination** for PC and **older & newer** pagination for mobile device. I achieved with PHP code using `wp_is_mobile` but there is a cache problem.

I don't want to use/change cache plugin for this implementation.

Would love to hear your implementation?

Thanks & Regards

Abhishek

Comment: Forget `wp_is_mobile`, and output the HTML code for _both_ pagination styles instead. Use CSS Media Queries to show one and hide the other, depending on the available width.

Comment: I tried this CSS implementation on Generatepress theme & it worked.  But in Genesis theme setting, either we can select one (prev/next) or (numeric) pagination type.

Don't know, how to do on Genesis theme.

Comment: If the theme only gives you the either/or option, then you will have to modify how the theme works. If it does not offer any hooks in the relevant places that would allow you to modify the result accordingly, then you will need to modify the respective template file - either within your child theme that you are hopefully using, if you want to be able to make such modifications, or in the original theme's file itself. The latter is of course never really advisable, if you don't want to break your ability to update the theme at some point.

Comment: Thanks, will try to modify, I have a doubt, won't it impact SEO?

Comment: Don't think that should make much of a difference, search engine bots will simply find a couple of links more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.